# Selecting Primes from list of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to use Select or Pick for selecting primes in all sublists.

```
list = {{2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 11}, {16, 17, 18}}
```

I can do it by

```
Table[Select[list[[k]], PrimeQ], {k, 3}]
```

or

```
Map[If[PrimeQ[#], #] &] /@ list /. Null -> Sequence[]
```

resulting in both cases in

```
{{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}
```

But I want to use Select or Pick for unknown values of k.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Select[PrimeQ] /@ list
```

Comment: Thanks! Very short and good!

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) with `PrimeQ @ list` as the selector array:

```
Pick[#, PrimeQ @ #] & @ list
```

> {{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}

or [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
Cases[_?PrimeQ] /@ list
```

> {{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}

Comment: Your first solution works fine, but to be honest: i don't understand the syntax!  Your second solution worked for   Cases[list, _?PrimeQ] on one dimesional list

Comment: @user57467, re the first method, `Pick[#, PrimeQ @ #] & @ list` is the same as `Pick[list, PrimeQ @ list]`. `Cases[_?PrimeQ] /@ list` should work for list of lists in versions 10+.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 11}, {16, 17, 18}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[#, {_?(Not @* PrimeQ)}] & /@ list
```

{{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}

Using `Position` and `Delete`

```
p = Position[list, x_ /; ! PrimeQ[x], 2, Heads -> False]
```

{{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 11}, {16, 17, 18}};
```

Using `Replace` at level `2`:

```
Replace[list, n_ /; ! PrimeQ[n] -> Nothing, {2}]

(*{{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `DeleteCases`:**

`DeleteCases` is suitable for nested lists as is maintains list structure while deleting any elements that match the pattern.

```
list = {{2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, {8, 9, 11}, {16, 17, 18}}

DeleteCases[list, _?(Not@*PrimeQ), All]
```

---

> {{2, 3, 5, 7}, {11}, {17}}